# Unknown method used in expression in activiti 6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, alfresco, activiti

After the migration from activiti 5 to 6 I have this error when init the app:

```
Caused by: org.activiti5.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown method used in expression: #{elCorService.makePlat(corWorkflowService.buildContext(execution))}
    at org.activiti5.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression.getValue(JuelExpression.java:56)
    at org.activiti5.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ServiceTaskExpressionActivityBehavior.execute(ServiceTaskExpressionActivityBehavior.java:71)
    ... 199 more

... Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy360.buildContext(org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntityImpl)
```

Comment: it might be better to ask this question on the activiti community: https://activiti.gitbook.io/activiti-7-developers-guide/community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible you have custom code that's referencing "org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity" instead of "org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntityImpl"? Specifically "corWorkflowService.buildContext()".

This is a documented change between 5 and 6: https://www.activiti.org/migration

```
5.7. EntityManagers

In Activiti version 5, all EntityManager (responsible for persistence but also certain 
logic) classes did not have an interface. In version 6, all EntityManager classes have 
been renamed to have Impl as suffix and an interface without the suffix. This 
effectively means that the version 5 EntityManager class name is now the name of the 
corresponding interface.

All EntityManager interfaces extend the generic 
org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.EntityManager interface. All 
implementation classes extend a generic AbstractEntityManager interface.

Also, for consistency: * The UserIdentityManager interface has been renamed to 
UserEntityManager * The GroupIdentityManager interface has been renamed to 
GroupEntityManager
```